# Titanium - Create custom function, calling the function and passing arguments

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am an iPhone developer and a beginner in using Titanium studio. I started to learn Titanium few days back and worked on some samples which uses view, navgroup, images, etc. I'd like to step advance. I can not find samples to create a custom function, calling a function in Google. So, someone here guide to how to create a simple function, calling a function and sample for passing arguments. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just JavaScript, so use it like JavaScript like below:

Example 1:

```
function myFunction(arg1,arg2){
   // do stuff here
}
```

Example 2:

```
var myFunction = function(arg1,arg2){
    // do stuff here
}
```

Calling function:

```
myFunction(value1,value2);
```

Memory wise it is best to do something like this:

```
var app = {};
app.myFunction = function(arg1,arg2) {}
```

Comment: In that last snippet, it'd be `var app = {};` wouldn't it?

Comment: so, the arg1 type could be any datatype?